# Duplicate every value in array as a new array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an numpy ndarray input like this

```
[[T, T, T, F],
  [F, F, T, F]]
```

and I want to duplicate every value as a new array, so the output would be

```
[[[T,T], [T,T], [T,T], [F,F]]
  [[F,F], [F,F], [T,T], [F,F]]]
```

How can I do this? Thank you in advance

Comment: tried at least some code?

Comment: Yeah but I was wondering if there was a one line method without using a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be using [`np.dstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) to replicate the array along the third axis:

```
np.dstack([a, a])

array([[['T', 'T'],
        ['T', 'T'],
        ['T', 'T'],
        ['F', 'F']],

       [['F', 'F'],
        ['F', 'F'],
        ['T', 'T'],
        ['F', 'F']]], dtype='<U1')
```

---

Setup:

```
T = 'T'
F = 'F'
a = np.array([[T, T, T, F],
              [F, F, T, F] ])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just use list comprehension:

```
data =[['T', 'T', 'T', 'F'],
  ['F', 'F', 'T', 'F'] ]

d = [[[i]*2 for i in j] for j in data]
print (d)
```

output:

```
[[['T', 'T'], ['T', 'T'], ['T', 'T'], ['F', 'F']], [['F', 'F'], ['F', 'F'], ['T', 'T'], ['F', 'F']]]
```